# How to solve this error in wine

Tags: linux, wine, playonlinux

I am a linux user 32 bit system. I recently installed microsoft office 16 via playonlinux. But when i run it, it doesnt work and gives me an error.This is the error`Error in POL_Wine Wine seems to have crashed` PLease help. Screenshots are also given below. Thanks[image]

[image]

Comment: Please anyone help

Comment: Guys please respond